# Alguma maneira de estilizar elemento "pai" com CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Olá, existe alguma maneira de selecionar o elemento pai de outro elemento com CSS?

Para ser mais especifico, estou estudando em localhost usando a plataforma de fóruns phpBB3, quando uma mensagem é agradecida ela ganha a classe `.bg1` (sendo que o padrão é `.bg2`).

Ambos `.bg1` e `bg2` são filhos diretos da classe `.pannels`, já essa não se altera estando a mensagem agradecida ou não.

Meu objetivo é estilizar a classe `.pannels` com um `background-color:#eaf8e2` apenas se o elemento filho dela for o `.bg1` caso seja o `.bg2` gostaria de manter a cor `#fff` no background.

```
<div class="pannels">
    <div class="bg1"></div>
</div>

<div class="pannels">
    <div class="bg2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por que você não faz isso utilizando jquery?

Comment: Estarei utilizando amigo.. Só gostaria de saber se havia alguma maneira de fazer isso em CSS antes de usar jQuery...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Não há atualmente nenhuma maneira de selecionar o pai de um elemento em CSS.

Nas especificações CSS, [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) e [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), não há nada nesse sentido, você vai ter que recorrer a JavaScript ([ou jQuery, `:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)) se você necessita selecionar um elemento pai.

---

**Atualização na Especificação**

Houve uma atualização nas especificações dos Seletores de Nível 4, onde a [pseudo-class `:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) parece ser a sintaxe escolhida para este proposito até o momento (Isto não é uma especificação final e pode sofrer mudanças, ou até mesmo ser removida por completo).

Isso não está disponível em nenhum browser até o momento (17/10/2017):

- [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas);
- [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has);

Com está pseudo-class a solução ao problema proposto na pergunta seria está:

```
div.pannels:has(> div.bg1) 
{ 
    /* styles serão aplicados ao "div.pannels" elemento que tenham um elemento filho "div.bg1"*/ 
}
```

Answer (score 12):

A isso se dá o nome de *parent-selector*, sendo que **não é possível fazer isso usando CSS3**.

Isso já foi proposto, e algo parecido [está para ser implementado pelos <s>CSS4</s><sup>*</sup> seletores de nível 4](http://loopinfinito.com.br/2012/06/24/novos-seletores-css4/), usando-se a marcação `$` antes do seletor da hierarquia ao qual o estilo será aplicado.

<sup>*</sup> segundo a referência, CSS4 não existe, mas sim, *[seletores de nível 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/)*.

**EDIT: correção**

Verificando pelo [rascunho de especificação da W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/), é possível verificar que o símbolo atualmente proposto é o `!` após o seletor a ser estilizado.