# CSS pegar siblings antes do elemento?

Tags: css, css-hover

Bem basicamente, tenho a seguinte estrutura, em que quando o `hover` é ativado em um elemento, os irmãos da direita devem receber um estilo exclusivo, enquanto os da esquerda devem receber um outro estilo. Atualmente tenho o mesmo código funcionando bem em JS para estilizar os irmãos a esquerda do elemento em `hover` porém, me sinto incomodado de não conseguir fazer tudo só com CSS, então a pergunta, é possível selecionar todos os irmãos antes do selecionado usando CSS?

```css
.main{
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
}
.child{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  
  background-color:#F00;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.child:hover{
  background-color: #0F0;
}
/*define cor para todos os siblings depois deste*/
.child:hover ~ .child{
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creio que não. O CSS só olha pra frente e pra baixo.

Comment: Leitura complementar: [Alguma maneira de estilizar elemento “pai” com CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13876/70)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS não tem seletor que resolva anterioridade, mas no seu caso um "duplo hover" pode resolver (funciona no IE11, inclusive):

```css
.main{
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
}

.child{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  
  background-color:#F00;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.main:hover .child{         /* o hover no main aciona a mudança no resto */
  background-color: #FF0;
}

.main:hover .child:hover,
.child:hover{
  background-color: #0F0;
}

.child:hover ~ .child{
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: É possível ativar uma cor diferente, caso o hover seja no último elemento?

Comment: pode usar o :last-child, ou mesmo por uma classe adicional nele. tem várias maneiras, qual a melhor, depende do projeto.

Comment: Tem vários posts sobre CSS no site que podem ser interessantes, veja alguns: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9183/70  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148591/70

Answer (score 5):

Tenho uma solução que pode servir. Mas tem uns poréns, o `container` tem que ser exatamente o tamanho dos filhos pra ficar legal. Precisa colocar no pai um hover seguido de uma regra `:hover:not()` nos filhos.

Veja que agora no `:hover` nos filhos eles ficam divididos em três partes, uma cor antes do hover, uma cor no elemento hovado e outra cor nos elementos irmaos.

```css
    .main{
      width: 250px;
      background-color:silver;
      display: flex;
    }
    .main:hover > .child:not(:hover) {
      background-color:#ff0;
    }
    .child{
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      background-color:#f00;
      border: 1px solid black;

    }
    .child:hover{
      background-color: #0F0;
    }
    /*define cor para todos os siblings depois deste*/
    .child:hover ~ .child{
      background-color: #00F !important;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="main">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

A [resposta do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/317491/3635) está ótima, no entanto aonde existem espaçamentos se passar o mouse acidentalmente neles o `:hover` ao elemento pai vai ser aplicado:

[image: hover do elemento pai]

Note como ficou amarelo, no caso do exemplo não ocasiona problemas, mas se por acaso precisar de algum efeito mais complexo no `hover`, isso pode ocasionar efeitos não esperados.

Para melhorar recomendo usar `pointer-events: none` e `pointer-events: auto` nos elementos filhos, exemplo:

```css
.main{
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  
  background-color:#F00;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.main:hover .child{ /* o hover no main aciona a mudança no resto */
  background-color: #FF0;
}

.main:hover .child:hover,
.child:hover{
  background-color: #0F0;
}

.child:hover ~ .child{
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Resultado:

[image: resultado com pointer-events]

Apenas para destacar, `pointer-events` só funciona no Internet Explorer 11 e navegadores mais modernos, felizmente funciona em desde versões bem antigas de navegadores populares:

- Opera 9.5 (lançado em 2008) - ps: no *caniuse* mencionam que é desde o Opera 9, mas estou quase certo que isso era suportado apenas no 9.5, então se tiver me enganado irei revisar essa parte da resposta
- Safari 4 (lançado em 2008)
- Firefox 1.5 (lançado em 2005)

Só o Internet Explorer foi um tanto quanto demorado para implementar isso, a versão 11 com suporte a `pointer-events` do navegador só foi lançado em 2013.

---

### Alternativas

Uma forma sugerida pelo [@costamilam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91006/costamilam), inverter a ordem dos elementos, isso é possível com `float:right` e com `display:flex` + `flex-direction:row-reverse`.

## Usando `float: right`

```css
.main {
  height:50px;
}

.child1,
.child2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#F00;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.child1:hover,
.child2:hover {
  background-color: #fc0;
}

.child1:hover ~ .child1,
.child2:hover + .child2 {
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<h2>Todos elementos a esquerda</h2>

<div class="main">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
</div>


<h2>Apenas um elemento a esquerda</h2>

<div class="main">
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

## Usando `flex-direction:row-reverse`

```css
.main {
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.child1,
.child2 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;      
  background-color:#F00;

  flex:1 1 auto;
}

.child1:hover,
.child2:hover {
  background-color: #fc0;
}

.child1:hover ~ .child1,
.child2:hover + .child2 {
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<h2>Todos elementos a esquerda</h2>

<div class="main">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
</div>

<h2>Apenas um elemento a esquerda</h2>

<div class="main">
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```