# Hover no elemento irmão não funciona

Tags: css, front-end, pseudo-classes

Tenho duas `<li>` que estou usando como botões e quero fazer com que quando eu passe o mouse em uma, a outra fique mais transparente. Quando eu faço no `botão 1`, o `botão 2` fica transparente. Mas quando eu faço no `botão 2`, não acontece nada no 1.

O que eu faço? Não achei nada na internet.

```css
.botao1:hover+.botao2 {
  opacity: 0.3;
  /* Funciona */
}

.botao2:hover{
  opacity: 0.3;
  /* Não funciona */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="botao1">Criptografar</li>
  <li class="botao2">Descriptografar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: O [combinador irmão adjacente `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) separa dois seletores e **corresponde ao segundo elemento** se e somente se **seguir imediatamente após o primeiro elemento** e ambos forem filhos do mesmo pai element.

Comment: uma das maneiras mais simples em browsers modernos: `ul:hover li {transparente}` `ul li:hover {sólido}` - (com o `:not` já postado como resposta evita ter que definir o sólido, mas como provavelmente você já vai setar algo a mais no ítem em hover, pode ser uma boa)

Comment: Possivelmente duplicada dessa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317473/137387

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Esse seletor *next sibling* só funciona em elementos que são irmãos diretos, filhos do mesmo pai.

```
.botao2:hover + .botao1 {
    opacity: 0.3; /* Não funciona */
}
```

Essa parte em especial a regra não é aplicada,  só vai selecionar o próximo e não o anterior, por esse motivo o estilo não terá efeito.

classe botao1 não é  irmão próximo do botao2, então o estilo não sera aplicado.

O `+` (mais) indica que o elemento seguinte no caso as `li's` estão dentro de uma única `ul` não são irmãos diretos.

Um possível solução é criar um script para lidar com essa questão.

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector('.botao1');
const btn2 = document.querySelector('.botao2');

function alternarOpacidade(btnAtivo, btnInativo) {
  btnInativo.style.opacity = '0.3';
  btnAtivo.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    btnInativo.style.opacity = '1';
  });
}

btn1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  alternarOpacidade(btn1, btn2);
});

btn2.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  alternarOpacidade(btn2, btn1);
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="botao1">Criptografar</li>
    <li class="botao2">Descriptografar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Mano fiz cm javascript msm. Ficou legal do seu jeio, acabei fznd outro mas bgdão mano, d vdd.

Answer (score 2):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar a pseudo classe CSS [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:not) em conjunto a pseudo classe CSS [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

```css
/*Aplica o estilo aos filhos de elementos <ul> cujo:
  1 - o dispositivo apontador esteja sobre esse elemento <ul>.
  2 - o dispositivo apontador não esteja sobre esses filhos.
*/
ul:hover> :not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Criptografar</li>
  <li>Descriptografar</li>
</ul>

<p>Outra lista:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Abrir</li>
  <li>Importar</li>
  <li>Salvar</li>
  <li>Exportar</li>
</ul>

<p>Outra lista com subitens:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Lista com subitens:
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item2</li>
</ul>
```

A [pseudo-classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) CSS de negação `:not()` seleciona elementos que não correspondem a uma lista de seletores.
O uso da pseudo-classe `:not()` deve se feito com cautela pois efeitos e resultados incomuns podem ocorrer ao usá-lo, [segue trecho da documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#description):

> - Seletores inúteis podem ser escritos usando esta pseudoclasse. Por exemplo, `:not(*)` corresponde a qualquer elemento que não seja um
>   elemento, o que obviamente não faz sentido, portanto, a regra nunca
>   será aplicada.
> - Essa pseudoclasse pode aumentar a [especificidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) de uma regra. Por exemplo, `#foo:not(#bar)` irá corresponder ao mesmo elemento que o
>   mais simples `#foo`, mas tem a maior especificidade de dois ids
>   seletores.
> - A especificidade da pseudoclasse `:not()` é substituída pela especificidade do seletor mais específico em seu argumento separado
>   por vírgulas assim fornecendo a mesma especificidade como se tivesse
>   sido escrito `:not(:is(X))`.
> - `:not(.foo)` irá corresponder a qualquer coisa que não seja `.foo`, incluindo `<html>` e `<body>`.
> - Este seletor corresponderá a tudo que "não for um X". Isso pode ser surpreendente quando usado com o [combinador para descendentes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator),
>   pois há vários caminhos para selecionar um elemento de destino. Por
>   exemplo, `body :not(table) a` ainda se aplicará a links dentro de um
>   `<table>`, já que `<tr>`, `<tbody>`, `<th>`, `<td>`, `<caption>`, etc.
>   podem corresponder à parte do seletor `:not(table)`.
> - Você pode negar vários seletores ao mesmo tempo. Exemplo: `:not(.foo, .bar)`é equivalente a `:not(.foo):not(.bar)`.
> - Se algum seletor passado para a `:not()` for inválido ou não suportado pelo navegador, toda a regra será invalidada. A maneira
>   eficaz de superar esse comportamento é usar a pseudoclasse `:is`, que
>   aceita uma lista de seletores indulgente. Por exemplo `:not(.foo, :pseudo-classe-invalida)`, invalidará uma regra inteira, mas
>   `:is(:not(.foo), :not(pseudo-classe-invalida))`corresponderá a
>   qualquer elemento que não seja `.foo`.

Comment: Eu não sabia que funcionária sem o `has`. Boa resposta!

Comment: @CésarRodriguez Eu estava pensando em editar a sua resposta é trocar o *"...só dá pra fazer..."* por *"...dá pra fazer..."*. Tem o comentário do Bacco na pergunta que também apresenta outra forma de solução com CSS.

Comment: mano eu conheço o :not e n é o que eu quero, pq tipo se eu tiver no vão entre os dois botões ai os dois sofrerão o efeito. Entende? Achou que vou tentar por JS msm.

Answer (score 1):

Em uma declaração CSS só dá pra fazer, usando o seletor `:has`.

Basicamente, o que está escrito é: sempre que uma `ul` contiver um `li` filho direto seu que está sendo apontado pelo mouse, todas as `li` filhas diretas da `ul` que não estão sendo apontadas devem receber aquele estilo.

O VSCode provavelmente apontará o `:has(>li)` (um `has` começando com `>`) como erro, mas no navegador, funcionará (se quiser detalhes de compatibilidade, procure no [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com)).

```css
ul:has(>li:hover) > li:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.3;
  /* Funciona */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="botao1">Criptografar</li>
  <li class="botao2">Descriptografar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Firefox 109.0.1 windows 64, nada acontece. Até tem flag pra habilitar, mas em geral, só user avançado sabe disso - e no Safari tá no Technology Preview - mais detalhes em https://caniuse.com/has