# Como aplicar hover em todos os *irmãos ou *filhos?

Tags: css, front-end, sass, css-hover

Boa noite Galera, essa é minha primeira pergunta aqui no forum, então desculpem se não formula da melhor forma.

O problema que estou enfrentando é de aplicar o efeito css :hover em todos os elementos irmãos ou filhos(pode variar). A seguir, vou por meio de uma imagem, exibir o DOM gerado para esclarecer melhor.
[image: DOM gerado]

Então, como falei, a necessidade é aplicar o efeito nos filhos de ".t-body-row", que são todos esses ".t-body-col" sem afetar os netos e bisnetos, etc...

Estava tentando aplicar a todos os irmãos de ".t-body-col:hover" , mas n consegui chegar a um código que suprisse minha necessidade.

Fiz diversos testes, todos sem sucesso.

Aplicando apenas ".t-body-row:hover{ background: #ccc}" o efeito é repassando para todo o ".t-body-row" em questão, porém eu preciso dividir o efeito, não permitindo que seja repassado para os demais.

Ps.: Solucionaria meu problema, se consegui-se aplicar :hover em todos os irmãos diretos de ".t-body-col" caso algum deles esteja sobre :hover.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos. Muito Obg

Comment: Se é que eu entendi direito: `.t-body-row:hover > .t-body-col { background: #ccc}`

Comment: Nesse caso ele propaga o efeito hover para os outros... O que eu preciso é que quando o mouse chegar sobre t.body-col todos os irmãos fiquem com o background diferente

Comment: O que eu fiz ai no exemplo é exatamente isso que vc descreveu. Ao fazer hover em t-body-row, os t-body-col DENTRO desse t-body-row ficam com bg diferente, mas se não é isso que quer, seria legal por uma imagem no seu post demonstrando como era pra ficar

Answer (score 0):

Italo fiz um exemplo simples que pode ser que te ajude. Mas já adianto que quando vc faz um `:hover` no filho, vc automaticamente tb está fazendo o `:hover` no pai. Resumindo vc não consegue mudar o pai quando faz o `:hover` no filho apenas com CSS

Veja o exemplo. Repare que vc pode ter efeitos distintos, porem fazendo `:hover` no filho vc não consegue evitar que o pai tb esteja com o estado de `:hover`, pois é um elemento dentro do outro...

```css
.t-body-row:hover > .t-body-col {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.t-body-row > .t-body-row:hover > .t-body-col {
    background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<div class="t-body-row"> t-body-row
    <div class="t-body-col">A</div>
    <div class="t-body-col">B</div>
    <div class="t-body-col">C</div>
    <div class="t-body-col">D</div>
    <div class="t-body-row"> t-body-row
        <div class="t-body-col">E</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">F</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">G</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">H</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Opção criando um *container* para agrupar o primeiro conjunto de elementos. Repare que eu criei uma `div` `com class="filho1"` que engloba o primeiro grupo de elementos, dessa forma vc consegue estilizar cada grupo independente, não sei se vc consegue mexer na estrutura do HTML, mas se conseguir essa telvez seja uma opção...

```css
.filho1:hover > .t-body-col {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.t-body-row:hover > .t-body-col {
    background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<div class="t-body-row"> t-body-row
    <div class="filho1">
        <div class="t-body-col">A</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">B</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">C</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-body-row"> t-body-row
        <div class="t-body-col">E</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">F</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">G</div>
        <div class="t-body-col">H</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hugocsl, diante mão agradeço sua ajuda...Eu entendi a ideia..Uma forma de solucionar o meu problema (estava pensando), era aplicar hover a todos os irmãos de t-body-col uma vez que um desses irmãos estejam sobe :hover. Mas não consegui nada 100% eficaz..

Comment: @ItaloBrito tranquilo jovem, só tenha em mente que quando vc faz hover em uma div que está dentro da outra vc na verdade está fazendo hover nas duas.... E mesmo o mouse estando sobre um elemento interno da div pai vc não consegue tirar os estilo do pai, caso ele tb tenha estilos quando hovado. Pelo visto esse é o seu caso... Vc até pode pesquisar sobre como mudar o estilo do pai interagindo no filho e vai ver que não é possível... Pode ler aqui inclusive https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13876/alguma-maneira-de-estilizar-elemento-pai-com-css

Comment: vc tem razão..dessa forma eu estava pensando em mudar a estratégia para gerar esse efeito hover por linha, evitando o t-body-row e partindo p t-body-col. A proposito, tem alguma sugestão de como eu poderia aplicar hover em todos os irmãos do mesmo tipo ?

Comment: Cara normalmente se usaria o seletor `~` mas ele só pega os irmãos para baixo, ele não vai pegar os elementos que estão acima dele. Eu fiz um **EDIT** na minha resposta as vezes pode te ajudar.

Comment: Essa resposta tb pode te interessar para entender melhor o que eu falei no comentário acima sobre não pegar os elementos para cima do irmão, só o que vem abaixo... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317473/css-pegar-siblings-antes-do-elemento/317489#317489

Comment: com certeza tu me ajudou muito, embora ainda não tenha conseguido resolver o problema como gostaria, mas a luz foi boa, acho que vou tentar algo no html, porém tbm será dificil pq esse html é dinâmico, gerado através de um componente recursivo, criando uma lista de subníveis. Mas vou tentar partir p isso. :-]

Comment: @ItaloBrito como te falei esse caso é difícil de resolver só com CSS. Mas boa sorte ai no projeto

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente @hugocsl.Mais cedo ou mais tarde dará certo meu amigo. Vlw pela ajuda e pela paciência. :-]